# How do you compare the client date and server date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a code that runs to select a date from calender, but I want to set the `current_date` to that of the server in the mentioned calender. And with a functionality that compares `client_date` with `server_date`.

Comment: you'll save yourself a lot of pain by passing the date as a string and converting it to the proper Date object on both sides.

Comment: what's your purpose for doing that? there might be innumerable other ways to solve the actual case.

Comment: Why is your nickname Balasaheb anyway? ;) (just a joke by trying to translate your name to Arabic which means friendless ;))

Comment: @MikeMyers thanks mike for translating my name in Arabic but for your kind information I have community with more than 1000 which are my friends...

Comment: +1 Thanks, nice to know! but what does it mean and in what language is it your nickname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible. As suggested elsewhere, you should convert the dates to strings for two reasons:

1. Easier to read/understand when you search for a bug
2. The "current time" is always different between client and server

To send the current date to the client, you can use a hidden form field or an AJAX request or a web service or REST or JSON or JSONP or ... well, there are too many methods to do it.

To compare dates, convert the string to a `Date` object and then use the usual methods to compare them (`compareTo()` in Java and `<`,`==`,`>` in JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the following way:

In Java

```
public class YourJavaClass{
 public static String getServerDate()
 {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    return cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
 }
}
```

In jsp

```
$('input.datepicker').datepicker(
{
    minDate : new Date(<%out.print(YourJavaClass.getServerDate());%>)
});
```

Comment: Don't you need quotes somewhere?

Comment: The datepicker i used here is jquery-ui datepicker

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to pass the current date from your server script to the template, so when the pages renders, javascript can access it and make comparison. This has obvious issue - if the user will leave the page open till next day, the date will be out of date.

Other way is to use asynchronous call to your back-end and obtain the date from there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to compare both dates with conversation to milliseconds. Both languages provides methods for it.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="">
  var myDate = new Date();
  var milliseconds = myDate.getTime();
</script>
```

**Java (JSP):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<%!
    Date myJavaDate = new Date();
    long myJavaMilliseconds = 0L;
    myJavaMilliseconds = myJavaDate.getTime();
%>
 var myJavaMillisondsInJs = <%= myJavaMilliseconds %>;
</script>
```

/* Put code here to compare between those dates */

If you want to compare the dateas server side you have to submit the javatime to the server via Ajax or a form.

Comment: Using milliseconds is a good idea because they are based on the same offset (1.1.1970). They are a bad idea because for any given point in time, the values on the client and the server will be different. And don't forget time zones and DST.

Comment: @Aron: You're right. As far as I could understand the question he knows the difference between serverside and clientside time (I suppose he knows it^^).